# String Permutations explanation?

Tags: java, string

I was looking up how to perform String Permutations and found the solution below. However I having real trouble understanding the logic being used. Especially this particular line. **for(final String permutation : Permuatations(subList(head,words)))** From what I can tell the author is calling a function on itself "Permutations" to perform the subList function within, which is very hard hard to wrap my head around. Could anyone make this a bit clearer to me? Any guidance would be much appreciated.

```
public static void main (String [] args)
    {
        for(final String s: Permuatations(Arrays.asList("This ","is ","String ")))
                {
            System.out.println("6. THE FINAL OUTPUT " +s);
                }
    }

    public static List<String> Permuatations(final List<String> words)
    {
        final List<String> perms = new ArrayList<String>();
        if (words.size() == 1)
        {
             perms.add(words.get(0));
             System.out.println("3. permuatations if words " + words);
             System.out.println("4. PERMS LIST " + perms);
        }

        else
        {
            for(final String head : words)
            {
                for(final String permutation : Permuatations(subList(head,words)))
                {
                    perms.add(head + permutation);
                    System.out.println("5 .SubList HEAD " + head + " PERMUATATION " + permutation  + " Word Size " + words.size() );
                }
            }
        }
        return perms;
    }


public static List<String> subList(final String elementToRemove, final List<String> elements)
{
    final List<String> subList = new ArrayList<String>();
    for(final String s : elements)
    {
        //System.out.println(" 1. STRING s " + s + " ELEMENTS " + elements);
        if(!s.equals(elementToRemove))
        {
            System.out.println(" 1. STRING S " + s + " ELEMENTS " + elements);
            subList.add(s);
            System.out.println("2 STRING S " + s + " TO SUBLIST " + subList);
        }


    }

    return subList;
}
```

Comment: Take a look at http://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/23recursion/ or just google for **"recursion"** or "**recursive function**"

Answer (score 2):

This is precisely what they're doing.  It's called recursion, and it's, well, hard to wrap your head around at first.   Imagine you have strings:

A  B  C  D

Effectively, what you do, is choose each string in turn and then find all permutations of the remaining strings, and prepend your chosen string.

```
Choose A, get all permutations of {B,C,D} and append A. 
Choose B, get all permutations of {A,C,D} and append B. 
Choose C, get all permutations of {A,B,D} and append C. 
Choose D, get all permutations of {A,B,C} and append D.
```

Now,  we have subproblems that look very similar, but are smaller. That's the heart of recursion.  Take a problem, and find a way to turn it into a smaller version of the problem.  Now, keep turning it into a smaller problem until it's trivial. Now we have to figure out how to generate permutations of 3 strings.

```
Permute(A B C) 
Choose A, get all permutations of {B,C} and append A.
Choose B, get all permutations of {A,C} and append B.
Choose C, get all permutations of {A,B} and append C.
```

Same structure, but smaller problems.   So take it a step further.  How do we do permute(A B)

```
Permute(A B) 
Choose A, get all permutations of {B} and append A.
Choose B, get all permutations of {A} and append B.
```

So now we just have to permute one string.  That's trivial.

```
Permute(A)
A
```

So now we have a way to Permute a list of strings of size 1, and we've defined how to permute a list of size N by Permuting a list of size N-1.  So, we can permute any list of size >= 1, by calling ourselves with a slightly smaller version of the problem.  That's the beauty of recursion.  You just define how to solve the smallest problem, and how to use that solution to build a bigger solution, and it builds upon itself.

Answer (score 0):

This is a recursive algorithm, it essentially takes each element in the array as the first one then adds to to it the output of calling itself without that element.

Take 3 elements A, B and C and walk through the logic, lets call our function `perm`.

so, we want

```
perm({A, B, C})
```

this equals

```
A + perm({B, C})
B + perm({A, C})
C + perm({A, B})
```

expand again

```
A + B + perm({C})
A + C + perm({B})
B + A + perm({C})
B + C + perm({A})
C + A + perm({B})
C + B + perm({A})
```

as `perm({X}) = X` we end up with

```
A + B + C
A + C + B
B + A + C
B + C + A
C + A + B
C + B + A
```

Answer (score 0):

The scheme used is "divide and conquer". It's basic idea is to break up a big problem into a set of smaller problems to which the same mechanism is applied until an "atomic" level of the problem is reached. In other words: A problem of size n is broken up into n problems of size n-1 continuously. At the bottom there is a simple way of dealing with the problem of size 1 (or any other constant). This is usually done using recursion (as Calgar99) pointed out already.

A very nice example of that scheme that will also twist you head a bit are the "Towers of Hanoi". Check it out and the ingenuity of such an approach will hit you.

As for the presented code: The permutation of n words is the concatenation of the permutation of n-1 words with each of the n original words. This recursive definition represents a quite elegant solution for the problem.

Comment: More examples: Recursive definition of Fibonacci numbers, the faculty operator (n!).